# Obtaining a Nested Model's Count in the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following two models:

```
photoalbums
 has_many:photos

photos
 belongs_to:photoalbums
```

When I show a list of all the photoalbums, I want to also say how many photos exist in the album:

Controller:

```
def index
    @photoalbums = PhotoAlbum.all
end
```

View:

```
<%# Get the number of photos per this album %>
<% @photos = Photo.find_by_photo_album_id(photoalbum.id) %>
<li><%= @photos.count %> Photos</li>
```

The above isn't allowing me to do `@photos.count` or `@photos.record` in the view.

Is there a better way to do this in the controller? I thought about perhaps an `include(:photos)` in the controller?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't allowing"? If you go to script/console and type the same thing, what is the value of @photos? Why would you not be using photoalbum.photos.count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1) In your view you need to write this..

```
<% @photos = Photo.find_all_by_photo_album_id(photoalbum.id) %>
<li><%= @photos.count %> Photos</li>
```

instead of find_by_photo_album_id find_all_by_photo_album_id.

Solution 2)

```
In controller

def index
   @photoalbums = PhotoAlbum.find(:all,:include => :photos)
end

In View

<% @photos = photoalbum.photos %>
<li><%= @photos.count %> Photos</li>
```

Comment: Thanks but should I be doing some type of EAGER, include type thing in the controller for performance reasons? trying to learn that stuff?